# How can i check if the data type in has been converted in SQL

Tags: sql

I have inserted csv file to my database(using bulk insert) and i did all the casting and converting that to change from nvarchar to decimal and everything worked correctly. 
for example i have column (amount with values like 24,020,264.00)
but when i tried to apply the sum() function i got the message"
**Operand data type nvarchar is invalid for sum operator.**
so why the data type has not been changed or how can i check the data type of column after converting

Comment: _"why the data type has not been changed"_ - did you insert into existing table or created new one during insert? What is the definition of the table

Comment: @PirosaysReinstateMonica, first i have created table to in insert the raw data (all of them were nvarchar) and then i converted all data to match the data type that i want for example( convert to date or decimal ) after that i tried to make calculations

Answer (score 0):

You should cast you column to corresponding datatype first and  then do aggregation.

```
SELECT SUM(CAST(Coulmn as decmal(18,2))) // change to desired type
```

Comment: I did already for each field, and now i want to make some calculations